# I need Help, in Aligning copied items to Powerpoint from Excel

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vertical-alignment

```
Sub ToPowerPoint()
Dim pApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pSilde As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
```

'I have declared here pp Objects

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

'Turning off screen updating

```
Set pApp = New PowerPoint.Application
pApp.Visible = True
```

'Setting up new pp instance

```
pApp.Activate
Set pPres = pApp.Presentations.Add
Set pSlide = pPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
```

'Adding up new presentation and slide within pp

```
pSlide.Select    
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("BC_WTB__DRAFT.xlsb")
'setting up here xl workbooks
'
wb.Activate
Worksheets("BS").Visible = True
Worksheets("BS").Select
Worksheets("BS").Range("G5:H5").Select
Selection.Copy
pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteRTF
**'copying some cell values here and below**
Worksheets("BS").Range("G12").Select
Selection.Copy
pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
pApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 193

Worksheets("BS").Range("H12").Select
Selection.Copy
pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
pApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 193
'I need to align pasted objects in one horizontal line
'without using Top or Left methods
```

'I need help after copied cells are pasted in pp, to align them in
'some vertical and horizontal line without using top or left method.

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't you use .Top or .Left properties?  They're properties, not methods, btw.

Comment: That seems like a pointless restriction.

Comment: Actually, the point is: I am updating the values in the excel sheet into the slide in pp. So, updating with embedded links, gives some times error. That's why I am taking the values in each cell one by one and then putting them in correct places in the slide

Comment: The PasteSpecial method is prone to throwing errors, usually because of timing issues. You might be better of searching StackOverflow for solutions to this problem rather than your current approach to the problme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExcelHelp.

If you are trying to aling objects in powepoint presentation you can use the native alingment and distribute functions.

Just adding this at the and of your code.

```
Dim myArray() As Variant, myRange As Object

myArray = Array("img1", "img2", "txt1")

Set myRange = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range(myArray)

    myRange.Distribute msoDistributeHorizontally, msoFalse
    myRange.Distribute msoDistributeVertically, msoFalse
    myRange.Align msoAlignLefts, msoFalse
```

You just need to change names of the defaut shapes in the array (names change because we have different languages).

If you need to aling left, or top or right use the last line, or distribute heights / widths

Comment: By changing names you mean, img 1 img 2 txt 1, to change them

Comment: Sorry, by could you be precise by showing what to change. I couldn't get it

Comment: Yes, your code, create a new presentation and slide, always with defaut names, like ‘image1’ you need to identify those names and put in the array to select... when selected you will be able to use alignment code